# How to remove NullPointerException apear when i try to get some object from database

Tags: nullpointerexception, rmi

Java code:
Here throw exception

**MainFram**
...

```
    public MainFrame(User u) {

    initComponents();
    this.u=u;
    jList1.setModel(model);
    afisareProduse();
}

    private void afisareProduse(){
    model.clear();
    ArrayList<Produs> produse = ClientController.getInstance().getProduse();
    for(Produs p: produse) model.addElement(p);

}
```

**method getProduse() mentioned above, from MainController**

**in this aplication i use rmi(remote method invocation) this explain why i have ClientController.getInstance().getProduse();**

```
    public ArrayList<Produs> getProduse(){

    List<Produse> produse = produseController.findProduseEntities();
    ArrayList<Produs> list = new ArrayList<Produs>();
    for(Produse p: produse){
        list.add(new Produs(p.getId(), p.getNume(), p.getDescriere(), p.getPret()));
    }
    return list;
```

Produs = its a bean how look like Produse, i used the Produs  in the communication between the client and database to comply MVC;

Produse = Entity classes from database;

produseController = instance of ProduseJpaController;

I hope I was clear. So thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Writing something of the form

```
ClientController.getInstance().getProduse();
```

simply results in confusion when encountering nulls. In the above you have 2 possible sources for a null (first and second method invocations).

I would recommend:

1. getting each intermediate value and inspecting it for a null as you proceed
2. Avoiding nulls generally, by preferring exceptions to null values indicating an error, and/or the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)
3. not chaining methods together like the above, since it leads to a break in encapsulation. You should check out the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) for how to invoke methods upon objects.

> The fundamental notion is that a given object should assume as little
>   as possible about the structure or properties of anything else
>   (including its subcomponents), in accordance with the principle of
>   "information hiding".

Comment: thnx, but i'm new in java programming, please tell me what i have to do, exactly